# How to translate javascript mouse events into jquery mobile touch events?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a newbie to mobile web applications. I tried to create some mouse draggable divs for a webpage. They work well on desktop. However, when I checked them on mobile devices, none of them works. I searched online for help, but the only thing I got is that I need to set touch events with jquery mobile. Some articles said something about using touchstart, touchmove and touchend, but no examples were ever provided.

Here's my script:

```
dragElement(document.getElementById("cn"));
dragElement(document.getElementById("ln"));
dragElement(document.getElementById("gn"));
dragElement(document.getElementById("sn"));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
    var pos1 = 0,
        pos2 = 0,
        pos3 = 0,
        pos4 = 0;
    if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
        // if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:
        document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
    } else {
        // otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:
        elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
    }
    function dragMouseDown(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        e.preventDefault();
        // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
        pos3 = e.clientX;
        pos4 = e.clientY;
        document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
        // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
        document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
    }
    function elementDrag(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        e.preventDefault();
        // calculate the new cursor position:
        pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
        pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
        pos3 = e.clientX;
        pos4 = e.clientY;
        // set the element's new position:
        elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
        elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
    }
    function closeDragElement() {
        // stop moving when mouse button is released:
        document.onmouseup = null;
        document.onmousemove = null;
    }
}
```

I've tried to replace the mouse events with corresponding touch events. But it didn't work.
It appears that I have to rewrite the codes in another framework. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

vmousecancel means mousecancel
vmousedown
vmousemove
vmouseout
vmouseover
vmouseup

for more examples : https://api.jquerymobile.com/category/events/

Before using, you have to get jquery.mobile library in to your workspace.

Comment: I imported jquery mobile and replaced mouse events into vmouse events, but still nothing happens. I think it should rewritten in jQuery framework which I'm new to.